# How Can I insert unmatched row from one table to another alternative table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with same structure

```
**t1**
+------+------+
| code |  vid |
+------+------+
| AAA  |   2  | - row1
| BBB  |   3  | - row2
| AAA  |   4  | - row3
| CCC  |   2  | - row4
+------+------+

**t2**
+------+------+
| code |  vid |
+------+------+
| AAA  |   2  | - row1
| BBB  |   3  | - row2
| AAA  |   4  | - row3
| CCC  |   3  | - row4
| DDD  |   4  | - row5
+------+------+

**Result table**
**t1**
+------+------+
| code |  vid |
+------+------+
| AAA  |   2  | - row1
| BBB  |   3  | - row2
| AAA  |   4  | - row3
| CCC  |   2  | - row4
| CCC  |   3  | - row5 New Inserted Row
| DDD  |   4  | - row6 New Inserted Row
+------+------+
```

I want to insert new records from table 2 to table 1. The rows row4 and row5 are unmathed rows and I want to added in table 1. 
How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
INSERT INTO t1
  SELECT t2.* FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1
      ON t1.code = t2.code AND t1.vid = t2.vid
  WHERE t1.code IS NULL AND t1.vid IS NULL
```